# Trouble understanding generic method in Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a method in Java that has a mixed return type (like you have in PHP).

This method is supposed take a simple user input string and, using Generics, convert it to the appropriate type and return that value.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static <T> T askUser(String message, Class clazz) throws NumberFormatException {
    // get the user input
    String inputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(message),
            className = clazz.getCanonicalName();
    // return a Boolean, Integer or String
    if (className.equals(Boolean.class.getCanonicalName())) {
        return (T) Boolean.valueOf(inputString);
    } else if (className.equals(Integer.class.getCanonicalName())) {
        return (T) Integer.valueOf(inputString);
    } else /*return the String*/ {
        return (T) inputString;
    }
}
```

And I'm running the code like this:

```
    String userName = name_game.<String>askUser("Please enter your name.", String.class);
    Integer userAge = name_game.<Integer>askUser("Please enter your age.", Integer.class);
    tellUser("So your name is %s and your age is %d...", userName, userAge);
    Boolean confirm = name_game.<Boolean>askUser("Is this correct?", Boolean.class);
    tellUser("You said %b.", confirm);
```

But I can't figure out how to get it working without the (T) casting, and passing the Class parameter also seems as though it could be avoided.

How can I write this method without having to resort to casting to (T) ?

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're writing Java, you probably shouldn't be writing it like you're writing PHP. And vice-versa.

Comment: What about other types - `Double`, `Float`, `Long`?

Comment: @Kayaman it's just an exercise for fun. What if I used reflection to invoke T.valueOf? Rohit it's just for fun and these are the only types I need for now.

Comment: @Ozzy You can't invoke `T.valueOf` like that.

Comment: @Ozzy For more fun, check this answer of mine - http://stackoverflow.com/a/18098098/1679863, which is about almost same problem.

Comment: FYI, there is no reason to use `CanonicalName`, just do `clazz == Boolean.class`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics don't give you the ability to:

> take a simple user input string and, using
>   Generics, convert it to the appropriate type and return that value.

For example: What if someone puts a `File` and want to convert it to a `Dog`?

You can possibly create a interface `CreatableFromString` with a `createFromString( String userData)` signature, wich instantiate proper object using given String.

Then, you have full type-safety and even without using generics - and you don't have to worry about `File<->Dog` situation because only classes that implements `CreatableFromString` can be put into askUser parameter.

The cons of this solution is that askForUser will return CreatableFromString, but you can make this generic:

```
Dog dog = name_game.createByUserAskDialog( "Please enter dog name.", Dog.class );
```

and:

```
public static <T extends CreatableFromString> T askUser(String dialogTitle , Class<T> clazz) {
    ...get "data" from user...
    return T.createFromString( data ) ;
}
```

If you want to translate user string to existing types, you can pass not `Class<T>` as argument but your factory:

```
public interface CreatableFromStringFactory<T> {
  public T createFromString( String s );
}

...

public class BooleanFromStringFactory implements CreatableFromStringFactory<Boolean> {
  public Boolean createFromString( String s ) {
    if ( s.equals( "yes" ) ) {
      return Boolean.TRUE;
    }
    return Boolean.FALSE; 
  }
}

...
booleanFromStringFactory  = new BooleanFromStringFactory();
...
Boolean c = name_game.askUser("Is this correct?",booleanFromStringFactory );
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static <T> T askUser(String message, Class<T> clazz) throws NumberFormatException {
    // ...
}
```

Internal casts and generic in front of method invocation can be avoided too with this declaration.

Comment: Internal casts can not be avoided by this, only the explicit generic parameters can. You still need to cast the return value to `(T)`

Comment: With the above, the call becomes `String userName = name_game.askUser("Please enter your name.", String.class);`

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be better to write some code to convert string to the appropriate data type and to have different methods for obtaining user's age, name and so on.